# regex: match text between two strings, but farthest right string

Tags: python, regex

So I am trying to parse out the stuff between a certain start `ser[` and end `]` but the thing is that sometimes there's brackets inside already leading to confusion. there's only one instance of this inside the pipe `|`.

text: `asdfsd|//ser["gnd[{}\"\"]sgd"]|//sgsdgsdgsdg`

attempt: `ser\[(.*?)\]`

actual: `"gnd[{}\"\"`

expected: `gnd[{}\"\"]sgd`

https://regex101.com/r/uD5eU0/2

Comment: `but farthest right string` Yet you go out of your way to find the shortest right string, where regex tutorials stress the default of `*` is match the `farthest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the pattern

```
'ser\[(.*)\]'
```

For example

```
>>> import re
>>> s = r'''asdfsd|//ser["gnd[{}\"\"]sgd"]|//sgsdgsdgsdg'''
>>> re.findall('ser\[(.*)\]', s)
['"gnd[{}\\"\\"]sgd"']
```